# Manhattan [Mobility Radeon HD 5000 Series] support on 10.10

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, video, ati, support

Not long ago, [Canonical published a database of supported components for Ubuntu](http://www.canonical.com/content/canonical-releases-world%E2%80%99s-most-comprehensive-date-component-catalog-linux), and I noticed, that my video card Manhattan [Mobility Radeon HD 5000 Series] have full support only at Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, but I have installed 10.10, and want to know, does it have support on this version too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a list of *Ubuntu certified* (tested by Canonical for OEMs) and *Ubuntu ready* (tested  by OEMs) hardware, that's **guaranteed** to work on the specific systems they were tested on.

This doesn't mean that hardware not on that list won't work fine with Ubuntu - but it's possible. This also doesn't mean that hardware on that list won't work with older, later, or future versions of Ubuntu - but, again, it's possible.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the comment! PS: I cannot get my video card working on Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: have you tried manually installing the latest fglrx ati driver.

Comment: Yes, I tried catalyst 11.5. It's working now, but have big performance problems and graphical bugs, but at least system boots without problems...